# Machine learning algos for English sentence conversion

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

Is there any machine learning algorithm developed to convert an english sentence and its voice ( active to passive or vice versa)?
I am thinking of developing a small tool for converting a english sentence from active to passive voice and vice versa. I want to know if there is any such tool(s) that already exist?

Comment: Well, I think, that this issue is not trivial. For archiving this you need to implement full syntactic analysis of input sentences and than implement translation of syntactic structure using special active/passive speech templates.

Comment: @Andremoniy, Thanks for your comment. yes, its a non trivial problem. After researching a bit, I cam across parts-of-speech tagging as the first step. I also need a dictionary and template or rule base to proceed.